# IntelliJ IDEA cannot debug web application?

Tags: maven, web, intellij-idea

I have a maven web application and built in the IntelliJ IDEA, and my configuration is below:

[server configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijcex.jpg)

[deployment configration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3w01.jpg)

[debug configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrpqp.jpg)

When I clicked the debug button at the right top corner, the console print the log as below but no matter how long I waited nothing else happened:

```
/Users/***/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/bin/catalina.sh run
[2017-12-05 07:36:18,122] Artifact autohub-webapp:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
objc[3108]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java...
```

So I unchecked the option "Pass environment variables" in the debug configuration, it just ran correctly but the breakpoint didn't work at all.

My IntelliJ IDEA is the latest ultimate version and involved with tomcat 8.5.

My question is: why the debug doesn't work?

Comment: Try getting the thread dumps from  the Tomcat JVM to see where it hangs, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544899. It may help if you reinstall Tomcat and your JDK, try the latest 1.8 build from Oracle and see if it helps.

Comment: I have checked the compatibility of the Tomcat and the JDK which turned out to be alright. and the IntelliJ IDEA also could be responded with my click or any other editable behavior.It just seemed that the deployment behavior of itself get stuck.